# MySql Error 1064 unique clustered index

Tags: mysql

```
create unique clustered index NIK1_PK on NIK1 (
 ID_PLAN ASC,
 NIK ASC
);
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `CLUSTERED` keyword for the creation of an index.

See here how InnoDB decides which index to make the clustered one: [Clustered and Secondary Indexes in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-index-types.html)